# for loop within a function to write multiple files

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm trying to write a function that will take all images in a file location and apply another function to them (specifically, apply gaussian blur with varying sigma to each image and then write each image to the same location).

```
require(EBImage)
blurpics=function(pics.location){
  x=list.files(pics.location)
  y=length(x)
  for (i in x)  {
    for (j in y)  {
      blurpic=function(x,y){
      pic=readImage(x)
      pic1=gblur(pic,sigma=16.9)
      pic2=gblur(pic,sigma=15.3)
      pic3=gblur(pic,sigma=13.75)
      pic4=gblur(pic,sigma=12.25)
      pic5=gblur(pic,sigma=10.8)
      pic6=gblur(pic,sigma=9.4)
      pic7=gblur(pic,sigma=8.05)
      pic8=gblur(pic,sigma=6.75)
      pic9=gblur(pic,sigma=5.5)
      pic10=gblur(pic,sigma=4.3)
      pic11=gblur(pic,sigma=3.15)
      pic12=gblur(pic,sigma=2.05)
      pic13=gblur(pic,sigma=1)
      writeImage(pic1,paste(y,"_01.jpg",sep=""),quality=70)
      writeImage(pic2,paste(y,"_02.jpg",sep=""),quality=70)
      writeImage(pic3,paste(y,"_03.jpg",sep=""),quality=70)
      writeImage(pic4,paste(y,"_04.jpg",sep=""),quality=70)
      writeImage(pic5,paste(y,"_05.jpg",sep=""),quality=70)
      writeImage(pic6,paste(y,"_06.jpg",sep=""),quality=70)
      writeImage(pic7,paste(y,"_07.jpg",sep=""),quality=70)
      writeImage(pic8,paste(y,"_08.jpg",sep=""),quality=70)
      writeImage(pic9,paste(y,"_09.jpg",sep=""),quality=70)
      writeImage(pic10,paste(y,"_10.jpg",sep=""),quality=70)
      writeImage(pic11,paste(y,"_11.jpg",sep=""),quality=70)
      writeImage(pic12,paste(y,"_12.jpg",sep=""),quality=70)
      writeImage(pic13,paste(y,"_13.jpg",sep=""),quality=70)
      #}    
    }
  }
}
```

One problem is that the function only works with one image in the file location.--- *UPDATE: the logical error was pointed out by baptiste*

More importantly, how can I rewrite this function more efficiently so that I dont have to define each pic variable separately?

Comment: you're making a loop with `i`, yet inside the loop you use `x`

Comment: I believe you're now after `for (j in seq_along(sigma))` and `sigma[j]` inside the loop. Note that your `k` isn't defined.

Comment: Yes, indeed, that was a typo created only when I posted the code. So addressing the question: is it possible to define j and k in the same for statement without nesting? The point again is to have k in order to number the images with integers from 1 to 13: `writeImage(pic1,paste(k,i,sep="_"),quality=70)` Thanks

Comment: what I suggested above, `seq_along()`, should work, have you tried it?

Comment: Ah, yes, didnt notice you were offering a solution. Works great, thanks! So just to wrap things up, I take it that it's not possible to have two non-nested variables in a `for` statement like j and k, and I have to wonder how one would go about it - say if I wanted k to be not just a sequence but something more complex like another blur setting to be matched with j. Would one use a different function instead of a loop? I'm trying to understand the limitations here.

Comment: once you've got integer indices `k in 1:length(sigma)` you can access the corresponding values from other vectors or lists or data.frames by simple indexing, `sigma[k]`, `letters[k]`, `iris[k, ]` etc.

Comment: Please do not edit in solutions into the question. Post an answer for that, instead.

Answer (score 1):

Just on the initial question, what you probably want for this kind of task is `lapply()` - it takes a list and applies a function to each element. You also, presumably, want to be able to factor the relative gaussian blur levels in, too. For that you'd want a list where each element contains two items; a file name, and a level of blur. So:

```
#List files
vector_of_file_names <- list.files(pics.location)

#List gaussian blur levels
gaussian_blur <- c(1,2,3,4)

#And now apply!
lapply(vector_of_file_names, function(x){

    #"x" is the filename
    pic <- readImage(x[[1]])

    for(i in seq_along(gaussian_blur)){

        #Apply gaussian blurring.
        pic = gblur(puc, sigma = gaussian_blur[i])

        #Write out
        writeImage(pic, paste(i, "blurred",x, sep = ""), quality = 70)
     }

})
```

Hope this helps. Generally the answer to "I have nested for-loops" is going to be "have a for loop/apply function running over a list of vectors, rather than a single vector".

Comment: I really like this solution, but can you look over and double check that the syntax is correct? I dont believe that the mapply does what you want it to; at least I think you want it to create a filenames x blur levels list but instead it associates each filename with a different blur level. Also, did you mean to write lapply(list_of_both ?

Comment: Ahh, I misread; you're looking to generate N blurred files for each original file, not just N blurred files? Will amend.

Comment: Try now? Hopefully it's fixed.

Comment: Works great now, thanks. I do wonder though due to the overall similarity to the non-apply solution if using lapply to read each value in x is advantageous.

Comment: The answer there is "it depends". So, for this specific situation, it doesn't make a tremendous difference which you use - but you should absolutely get used to lapply and know how to work with it, if you're looking for speed increases. The long and the short of it is that lapply is a lot faster than a for loop for a lot of iterative operations because it writes to a list - see [http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html#modification-in-place](this wonderful explanation) of why.

Answer (score 0):

Moving my solution from the OP: With baptiste's help, here is the solution I was originally seeking, and kudos to Ironholds for the alternative solution:

```
blurpic=function(pics.location){
 require(EBImage)
  require(tools)
   x=list.files(pics.location)
   sigma=c(16.9,15.3,13.75,12.25,10.8,9.4,8.05,6.75,5.5,4.3,3.15,2.05,1)
   for (i in seq_along(x))  {
     for(j in seq_along(sigma)) {
      pic=readImage(x[i])
      pic1=gblur(pic,sigma=sigma[j])
      #writeImage(pic1,paste(file_path_sans_ext(x[i]),j,".jpg",sep=""),quality=70)
      writeImage(pic1,paste(i,"_",j,".jpg",sep=""),quality=70)
    }
  }
}
```

Note: I've added two writeImage possibilities for naming according to the original filename or naming by sequence.